# convert class to another class with json(Jackson framework)

Tags: java, json, jackson

Two classes have similar fields, but they don't have superclass. In my code : `First` and `Second` classes. I need to write method `convertToAnother`, what will be return object of class `resultClassObject` with values of fields from object `one`.
Both classes have Json annotation. That annotation have vaule of property equals name of class in lowercase (in my code class `First` have `className = "first"`.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Second s = (Second) convertOneToAnother(new First(), Second.class);
        First f = (First) convertOneToAnother(new Second(), First.class);
    }

    public static Object convertOneToAnother(Object one, Class resultClassObject) throws IOException {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String obj = mapper.writeValueAsString(one);
            obj = obj.replace("\"className\":\"" + one.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "\"", "\"className\":\"" + resultClassObject.getSimpleName().toLowerCase() + "\"");
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(new StringReader(obj), resultClassObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  property="className")
    @JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=First.class,  name="first"))
    public static class First {
        public int i;
        public String name;
    }

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  property="className")
    @JsonSubTypes(@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=Second.class, name="second"))
    public static class Second {
        public int i;
        public String name;
    }
}
```

Maybe another decision exist?

Comment: can't you just write converting methods by hand? A method that accepts `First` as a parameter and returns `Second` and vice versa? Json mappers (and using reflection) is nice if you need something generic but will be slow. Not a problem if you're not going to use it a lot though. Other generic option would be to use reflection manually, then you don't need to convert to String.

Comment: of course I can, but my task require to use Json. 
Firstly, i trying to convert class using `mapper.convertValue(one, resultClassObject);` and get Exception:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve type id 'first' into a subtype of [simple type, class com.javarush.test.level33.lesson05.home04.Solution$Second]`
than I understand, that need change `id` from "first" to "second" and it will worked, but this code failed tests from validation program.

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way to do that using jackson is to marshall instance to json and then unmarshall. I would recommend to use convertion on the level of java objects - using Dozer: http://dozer.sourceforge.net

Comment: Dozer is discontinued now.

Answer (score 1):

I want to offer such a solution, example for class First:

```
First first = new First();
first.i = 1;
first.name = "first";
Second s = (Second) convertOneToAnother(first, Second.class);
System.out.println(s.name); // first

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

// here we disable uses annototions, since by the condition of the 
// problem, we have two classes have similar fields
mapper.disable(MapperFeature.USE_ANNOTATIONS);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
mapper.writeValue(writer, one);
//writer.toString() == {"i":1,"name":"first"}

mapper.readValue(writer.toString, resultClassObject);
```

if we don't use method mapper.disable(), we'll have for writer, such string `{"className":"first","i":1,"name":"first"}`

Comment: Welcome to SO, we appreciate your input! Could you please edit your answer and explain a bit what you are doing and why? For more guidance see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can write code like below for model mapping:

```
public class ModelConverter {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Test1 t1 = new Test1();
    ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper1.writeValueAsString(t1);
    System.out.println(jsonString);
    Test2 t2 = mapper1.readValue(jsonString, Test2.class);
    System.out.println(t2);
}
}
public class Test1 implements Serializable {
private int i = 10;
private String name = "demo1";
private Test3 test3 = new Test3();

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Test3 getTest3() {
    return test3;
}

public void setTest3(Test3 test3) {
    this.test3 = test3;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "test1 [i=" + i + ", name=" + name + ", Test3=" + test3 + "]";
}
}
public class Test2 implements Serializable {
private int i = 11;
private String name = "demo2";
private Test3 test3;

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Test3 getTest3() {
    return test3;
}

public void setTest3(Test3 test3) {
    this.test3 = test3;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "test2 [i=" + i + ", name=" + name + ", Test3=" + test3 + "]";
}
}

public class Test3 implements Serializable {
private int i = 12;
private String name = "demo3";

public int getI() {
    return i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
    this.i = i;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "test3 [i=" + i + ", name=" + name + "]";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of task would be right to use object mappers like Dozer (http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Dozer is discontinued now.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace value of className without String manipulations

```
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader();

JsonNode node = reader.readTree(writer.toString());

((ObjectNode)node).put("className",resultClassObject.getSimpleName().toLowerCase());
```

Also if you don't know the name of the field where name of the class is stored, but you know it is in the annotations, you can try and get the first field from JsonNode (in your code you assume that the field name is "className", but what if it is not).

```
ObjectMapper mapper1 = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> result = mapper1.convertValue(node, Map.class);
String key1 = result.keySet().toArray()[0].toString();
```

And now you can replace the value for the key1 field, which should be the field where class name is stored.

Comment: Your question about assuming that the field name is `className` is valid, but poorly put.  To improve the quality of your answer I suggest still using `className` in your second code segment and changing the contents of your bracketed comment to `(in your code you assume that the field name is "className", but you can call it just about anything else if you wish)`.

Comment: I don't want to say that you can call it how you wish. It didn't mention in the question that field name is "className". _"That annotation have value of property equals name of class in lowercase"_ - that is it, so the name field is not fixed or controlled by conversion function